# slam Gmapping from bag only take partial data

Tags: navigation, rosbag, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i,ve managed to create some bags starting from some carmen log file.
Now i'm trying to use those bags with for gmapping but while rosbag play doesn't show any error, gmapping get stuck at:

```
update frame 0
update ld=0 ad=0
Laser Pose= 0 0 0
m_count 0
Registering First Scan
```

so when i try to get the map file using "rosrun map_server map_saver" only a partial map file is given.

While doing this procedure with the bag given in the gmapping from logged data tutorial nothing get wrong.

one of the bags i'm trying to use is this: db.tt/BawU5lXp

Is there a way to check if the bag is suitable for what i'm doing ? what can be the problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94826/slam-gmapping-from-bag-only-take-partial-data/) by [loppo](https://answers.ros.org/users/7001/loppo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try playing your bag as follows......

$rosparam set use_sim_time true

$rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 100

$rosbag play --clock <your-ros-bag.bag>

Hope it works.

---

Originally posted by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) with karma: 167 on 2013-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0